# Spotify Android Player refreshing authentication

Tags: spotify

I'm using the implicit authentication API (because I don't currently have and don't plan to ever have a server that the app connects to that I could send a private token through), which seems to work fine even though it needs to refresh pretty frequently, but I'm having trouble with the player itself falling out and failing to play because the authentication has expired, and I'm not sure what the correct method of refreshing the authentication is, or detect when it has failed an operation because of a lapsed authentication, since the callbacks don't seem to indicate that.

Ideally I'd like to be able to refresh the auth key while a song was playing (because the web api requests all do check for and correctly refresh the key when necessary).

So, what should I be watching, and what calls should I be making on the player?  Will a login() call correctly refresh the token even if it's already logged in?